# Keeps loading on startup

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-gio

My Samsung Galaxy Gio keeps loading when I turn on my phone. I've installed a custom rom, in the recovery mode, and I think I did something wrong. I don't know what to do, because the only thing I see is the startup screen. How to fix this? This is my only phone, so I have to fix this quickly. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please be specific about what you did.  If you have a custom recovery, try doing a factory reset and flashing a stock ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are in a boot loop. If you are sure that you installed a ROM that is supported on your device, go back in to the recovery and make sure you wipe the DATA and CACHE. If you reboot after doing so, and you still get the boot loop, then I would do as Matthew Read suggests and flash the Stock ROM back.